# Easy but complicated proposition in Fulton's book

Tags: algebraic-geometry

W. Fulton's *Algebraic Curves: An Introduction to Algebraic Geometry* defines the following sets:

[image]

I'm trying to prove first the $(V^*)_*=V$, but I'm stuck with a lot of recurrence definitions,  see (Remark: to avoid confusion I'm using the algebraic set $W$, instead of $V$):

$(W^*)_*=V(I_*)=\{p\in \mathbb A^n;f(p)=0,\forall \in f\in I_*\}=\{p\in \mathbb A^n;f(p)=0,\forall \in p;f={g_1f_1}_*+\ldots {g_nf_n}_*,g_i\in k[X_1,\ldots X_n],f_i\in I=I(W^*)\}$

but $I(W^*)=\{h\in k[X_1,\ldots X_n];h(q)=0,\forall q\in W^*=V(I^*)\}$, i.e., $l(q)=0,\forall l\in I^*$, i.e., for every $l=w_1l_1^*+\ldots w_nl_n^*, l(q)=0$, $w_i\in k[X_1,\ldots, X_n], l_i\in I=I(W)$, i.e., $l_i(s)=0$ for every $s\in W$.

I need help

Thanks in advance

Comment: "Easy but complicated..."?

Comment: @PeterTamaroff it seems easy, we have just to use the definitions above, but becomes complicated because of the large amount of definitions intercorrelated.

Comment: Dear user, Why don't you first try this for a principal ideal, so you just have *one* polynomial $f$ to think about?  This may make things clearer.  Regards,

Comment: "In Fulton's book..." Fulton has more than one book; could you be more specific?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark algebraic curves

Answer (score 4):

Note, if an ideal is being generated by a collection of elements $\{f_i\}$ (e.g. $I_*$ is generated by the elements $F_*$ with $F \in I$), then 
$f(p) = 0$ for all $f \in I$ if and only if $f_i(p) = 0$, where $f_i$ runs over the generating set.  So for example there is no need to introduce the $g_i$ in you definition of $V(I_*)$.

Also, note that $W^*$ is the variety cut out by the ideal $I(W)^*$ (by definition), so $I(W^*)$ is equal to the radical of $I(W)^*$.  With a little argument you should be able to get around taking this radical, and hence get yourself in a situation where $I(W^*) = I(W)^*$, which is the ideal generated by $F^*$ with $F \in I(W)$.

At this point you should be reduced to understanding $(F^*)_*$, at which point things will hopefully become clear.

---

As I suggested in my comment above, you might first want to take the case where $W$ is cut out by a single irred. polynomial $F$.  This will simplify things, but still captures the spirit of the question.

Comment: what do you mean by _where $f_i$ runs over the generating set_?

Comment: @user42912: Dear user, I mean $f(p) = 0$ for all $f \in I$ if and only $f_i(p) = 0$ for each member $f_i$ of the generating set.  Regards,